# Last Pass is neither auto-filling or auto-logging in for my Facebook account

Tags: facebook, passwords, login, lastpass

These are the settings I have for my Facebook account in LastPass:

[image: screenshot]

When I visit Facebook.com, there is no auto-login or filling the username and password:

[image: screenshot]

What's wrong?

Comment: I've duplicated your issue. But i've also duplicated it on `login.php`. I'm checking into possible javascript badness they have because the form field names are stored correctly within my lastpass vault.

Comment: I can't find anything about this. But if you click the Autofill button yourself (from the plugin/extension menu) it will work. <-- not an answer because it doesn't reflect the question.

Comment: @Dez I already knew about clicking the auto fill button from the extension menu.

Comment: Check if you've set never autofill for this domain in last pass, I did this once for facebook mistakenly too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bookmark and use https://www.facebook.com/login.php instead - the signup form that Facebook also put on the frontpage facebook.com causes issues with Lastpass.

Comment: this is not working for me.. Even clicking `Alt+i` doesn't popup a bar showing buttons for Auto Fill and Auto Login. However I can fill the username and password by right click on the page and then choosing `Lastpass -> Autofill -> (click on username)